# Awk - How to change format of the last field and keep the format same for other fields

Tags: awk

```
data="blue yellow red white foo.bar.com,foo.bar.eu" 

echo $data | awk '{printf "%-10s %-10s\n", $1, $5}'
```

gives me the following output:

`blue        foo.bar.com,foo.bar.eu`

I want the output to be as shown below by replacing comma in the last field with newline and align the last field as shown below.

`blue        foo.bar.com`

`foo.bar.eu`

Comment: Is it possible the fifth field can contain more than one comma?

Comment: Yes. The fifth field can have more than one comma separated URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "align" (tab-separated or visually tabular):

```
$ echo "$data" | sed 's/ .* /\t/; s/,/\n\t/'
blue    foo.bar.com
        foo.bar.eu

$ echo "$data" | awk -F'[, ]' -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $5 ORS "", $6}'
blue    foo.bar.com
        foo.bar.eu

$ echo "$data" | sed 's/ .* /\t/; s/,/\n\t/' | column -s$'\t' -t
blue  foo.bar.com
      foo.bar.eu

$ echo "$data" | awk -F'[, ]' -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $5 ORS "", $6}' | column -s$'\t' -t
blue  foo.bar.com
      foo.bar.eu
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/\([^ ]*\).* \([a-z]*\.[a-z]*\.[a-z]*\),\(.*\)/\1\t\2\n\t\3/' input_file
blue    foo.bar.com
        foo.bar.eu
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just add comma to the field separator:

```
echo "blue yellow red white foo.bar.com,foo.bar.eu" |
awk -F '[[:blank:],]+' '{printf ("%-10s %s\n%-10s %s\n", $1, $5, "", $6)}'

# gives
blue       foo.bar.com
           foo.bar.eu
```

- `%-10s` means make this string at least 10 characters wide, padding with spaces if necessary. The `-` means align the string to the left of the padded space (instead of to the right).
- You shouldn't do `%-10s\n` - this creates padding before a new line.
- To pad the second line the same as the first, you can use an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want:

```
echo "blue yellow red white foo.bar.com,foo.bar.eu,foo.baz.com" |
awk '{
    n=split($5, a, ",")
    printf "%-10s %-10s\n", $1, a[1]
    for (i=2; i<=n; ++i) printf "%10s %-10s\n", "", a[i];
}'
```

Output:

```
blue       foo.bar.com
           foo.bar.eu
           foo.baz.com
```